# Image preview using Ajax:returns a broken image icon

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a image preview function using Ajax.

When I was trying I have some questions pop up:

1. when the Ajax had runned, does the image itself has been uploaded to the server? Or just an array has been sent including strings name, type, size, tmp_name?
2. the code below returns a broken image icon.

I have tried:

HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/googleapis.js"></script>


<input multiple type="file" id="myFile" size="50">

<div id="sub">submit</div>

<div id="testtest"></div>



<script>
$("#sub").click(function(){
    // get the file objects
    var files = $("#myFile")[0].files,
        data = new FormData;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        //test if the files[i] has the file objects
        console.log(files[i]);
        //post objects to another php file
        data.append('img[]', files[i]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "testphp.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result){
            $("#testtest").html(result);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

PHP file (test.php)

```
<?php

$file_name=$_FILES['img']['name'][0];
$file_tmp=$_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][0];
var_dump($file_tmp); // for test if the variable has been post successfully
echo "<img src='".$file_tmp."'>";
?>
```

Comment: files require a valid enctype

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Can you try by passing the 'FormData' object directly to the PHP script instead of appending anything to it. and then iterating the image array in the PHP script itself.

Comment: Ok, i dont understand. Why would you use image preview through ajax. Why not use filereader to preview the image which bypass images going into server?  Anyway, try adding in `mimeType: "multipart/form-data",` in ajax

Comment: File reader seems too overwhelming for me as beginner...Do you know a more friendly tutorial other than https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications?

Answer (score 0):

Here to add in image preview https://jsfiddle.net/bhx0s2dh/2/

It is not that hard to use filereader.

HTML

```
<input id="image" type="file" multiple></input>
<div id="image-preview"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#image').change(function () {  //whenever the input changes
    PreviewImage(this);
});

function PreviewImage(source) {
    if ( !! window.FileReader) { //check if browser supports file reader
        $('#image-preview').html(''); //wipe the preview container
        var files = source.files;  //get the file from the input
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i].name;  //get the file name *if you need it*
            $reader = new FileReader(); //initialize file reader
            $reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]); //read the file
            $reader.onload = function (e) {  //load the result
                $('#image-preview').append('<div class="images"><img src="' + e.target.result + '" ></div>'); 
                  //e.target.result is the src
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.images {
    float:left;
}
.images img {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width:200px;
    max-height:200px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfect!  When the file object posted to php file, such as
fileName: "07.png"
fileSize: 33022
lastModifiedDate: Date
name: "07.png"
size: 33022
type: "image/png"
webkitRelativePath: ""
Does the file itself(with a lot of bytes) also be transferred to the server-side? Or only the above property value pairs has been transferred.
I'm unclear about what under the hood of file object post.

Comment: It doesnt transfer to server. This bypass the server. What this does is allow browser to do display images from client's local drive.